# Access violation exception in Matlab compiled function from C++

Tags: c++, matlab, exception, access-violation, extern

I have written a C++ code that is supposed to call some Matlab code. I have compiled all my Matlab files using the following command:

mcc -v -W cpplib:libParameter -T link:lib Parameter

I have included the header, DLL and LIB files created by above command in the 'Header Files'for my Visual Studio project. I have also include mclmcrrt.lib, mclmcrrt.h and mclmcppclass.h in the same.

Here is my C++ code:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Entered main function\n";
    if (!mclInitializeApplication(NULL, 0))
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not initialize the application properly."
            << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //Initialize all libraries
    if (!libParameterInitialize())
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not initialize the library properly."
            << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    LSTMDecode("configs\forward.m", "configs\backward.m");
    return 0;
}
```

It throws an access violation exception (picture attached) at this line: if (!libParameterInitialize())

[image: Access Violation Exception while executing libParameterInitialize function from Matlab compiled DLL]

I can see that the function is delcared in the header file: `bool MW_CALL_CONV libParameterInitialize(void);`

Can someone help me understand why this error occurs, what it means, and how can it be resolved?

**EDIT:** stack call

Stack Trace (from fault):

[  0] 0x00000000fe11ba23 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\win64\libmx.dll+00113187 matrix::detail::noninlined::mx_array_api::mxCreateString+00000083

[  1] 0x000000ecd07521c7 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\win64\mclmcr.dll+01188295 mclGetCtfStreamFromCallBack+00043191

[  2] 0x000000ecd0783239 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin\win64\mclmcr.dll+01389113 mclGetString+00000217

[  3] 0x000000018001664b C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\runtime\win64\mclmcrrt9_0.dll+00091723 mclGetString_proxy+00000059

[  4] 0x00007ff61a6b75c4  D:\abprak\NeuroConCPP\NeuroConCPP\NeuroConCPP.exe+00030148

[  5] 0x00007ff61a6bddfb  D:\abprak\NeuroConCPP\NeuroConCPP\NeuroConCPP.exe+00056827

[  6] 0x00007ff61a6c5b3a  D:\abprak\NeuroConCPP\NeuroConCPP\NeuroConCPP.exe+00088890

[  7] 0x00007ff61a6c6364  D:\abprak\NeuroConCPP\NeuroConCPP\NeuroConCPP.exe+00090980

[  8] 0x00007ff8103f13d2                   C:\windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL+00005074 BaseThreadInitThunk+00000034

[  9] 0x00007ff8105f54e4
C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00087268 RtlUserThreadStart+00000052

Comment: You can  not print using std::out, you need to use `mexPrint()`!!

Comment: @AnderBiguri This is not a mex file but compiled matlab code.

Comment: Is you library (libParameter) compiled in x64 while your C++ code would  be compiled in x32 ? ... If not, it may be also the calls to `mclmcrInitialize()` and `mclRunMain` which are missing**, see this full [integration example](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015b/compiler_sdk/cxx/integrate-a-cc-shared-library-into-an-application.html) on Mathworks website (**: unless you are using older runtime version with different initialization caling order)

Comment: Can you run the code under a debugger? Can you show the full stack at the exception site?

Comment: Added in the question.

Comment: I have the same problem